# react/axios -- not able to get data by API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

I am working on React first time, I am doing a API call in my react code. I am following an example from net. The example working perfectly. And I am following same way and implemented my API call. API call is successful. but I am assigning the response to an object and printing it in the console, but my object printing as unknown.

My code:

```
export const getXFlowdata = async () => {
    try{
        const {data} = axios.get(xurl, { headers: headers });

        console.log('Data: ', data)
        console.log('Data Type: ',typeof data)
       
        return data;
 
    }catch(error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Data:  undefined
>
> Data Type:  undefined

Example I fallowing:

```
export const getPieData = async () => {
    try{
        const {data} = await axios.get(baseUrl);
        console.log('Data: ', data)
        console.log('Data Type: ',typeof data)
        return data;
    }catch(error){
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Data:  {confirmed: {…}, recovered: {…}, deaths: {…}, dailySummary:
>
> Data Type:  object

Comment: `axios.get` --> `await axios.get`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a promise rather the data itself because you have not written await inside an async function and the promise
does not have any property data because it is not resolved yet.

```
  export const getXFlowdata = async () => {
    try{
        const {data} = await axios.get(xurl, { headers: headers });

        console.log('Data: ', data)
        console.log('Data Type: ',typeof data)
       
        return data;
 
    }catch(error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```